# jmeter plugins cmd runner

Tags: java, jmeter

I am running the the following:

```
java -jar /opt/jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/lib/ext/CMDRunner.jar \
--tool Reporter --generate-png /home/nune/jmeter_test/target/jmeter/results/RTOT.png \
--input-jtl A.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime
```

command from the `terminal.PNG` file is successfully creating but the process is not ending.

How can I resolve this issue. I want to end process after picture is successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the image is still being generated possibly due to lack of memory, in this case add after java

```
  -Xmx256m
```

An other option is head issues, then add after java

```
 -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

If none of those work, run on the pid of process:

```
 jstack -l pid
```

and show output here